# Model choice with non-random selections from upper and lower parts of a Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, model

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**
The initial point was to do analysis for family differences of skin immune reaction, as a percent of the skin with mucous. But the family differences are not available as I don't have enough samples from each families to do anything statistically.

**What I want to do now is find the correct model(s) for estimating:**

- Establish if there is a difference in weight between the sexes.
- What's the correlation between weight and infection rate (outcome).
- What's the effect of having a parasite on the sample site in
  question?
- What's the correlation between sex and infection rate (outcome) (and 
  control for weight differences if it's different).

The most important variables for me is parasite count and skin immune state (amount of mucus) as that's where correlations would be most interesting. Is there correlation between sex and immune response? is there differences between having a local infection on mucus levels or not?

**Original text**

I asked earlier about what to do about my dataset, but didn't get any answers.

I'll make it shorter this time in hopes that I'll get the answers I'm looking for. I'm not very good at stats, but I need to get my thesis done in a couple of months so I hope I can get my head around this:

I collected skin samples of fish with either very high or very low numbers of parasites, from a setup where there was added about 35 parasites pr. fish in a large tank.

I've collected data relating to their sex, immunological numbers from skin, weight etc.

Now I'm sitting here with a lot of different values, but not really sure where to start with it all. I wonder if I should treat the amounts of parasites as the only outcome variable, as the immunological data can't be evaluated in this way since it's only a single event sampling.

I tried to determine if the two groups (high and low) differed by weight by using GLM. I did this because I wanted to look at these as groups. But I'm not sure. Maybe I should treat them as two populations of data and compare them? In that case, whats' the best approach?

Any input would make my life much easier as I've struggled with this for some time.

Comment: I don't see enough information here to help people understand what you want.  What's the *purpose* of this analysis?  Are you trying to learn about the data, are you testing hypotheses, are you estimating quantities, or something else?  What do you want to learn, what hypotheses do you need to test, what needs to be estimated, ... ?

Comment: Did a shorter more precise wording at the top in the edit, is that okay?